# OnSelectedIndexChanged event stopped firing after I added autoComplete to dropdownlist. Any ideas why?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

We have a dropdownlist control with id of `NewEmpName`. This dropdownlist is automatically populated from the database with employee usernames. Users of this app use it to make requests.

When a user logs into this system, his or her name, along with other relevant information are automatically populated into several textboxes based on the user's login name.

If the user that logged into the system is making a request for another employee, this user selects the name of the employee sh/e is making the request on behalf of.

By selecting the name of the employee from the `NewEmpName` dropdownlist, the textboxes containing the records of the logged on user are replaced with information belonging to the employee just selected from the dropdownlist.

This is possible by using `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event

```
Sub ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    empname.Text = CType(sender, DropDownList).SelectedValue
```

Everything was working great until I was asked to add AutoComplete feature so users can type a few characters and select the name of the employee from the dropdownlist.

After adding this AutoComplete feature, `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event is no longer firing.

Any ideas?

Here is the dropdownlist codebehind:

```
Public Sub FillUsers()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select SAMAccountName from ActiveDirectory order by SAMAccountName ASC", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString))
    cmd.Connection.Open()

    Dim ddlValues As SqlDataReader
    ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    newEmpname.DataSource = ddlValues
    newEmpname.DataValueField = "SAMAccountName"
    newEmpname.DataTextField = "SAMAccountName"
    newEmpname.DataBind()
    Me.newEmpname.Items.Insert(0, "newEmpname")

    cmd.Connection.Close()
    cmd.Connection.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Part of the AutoComplete code that integrates with dropdownlist code:

```
Class Item
    Private _val As String
    Private _id As String

    Public Property sAMAccountName() As String
        Get
            Return _val
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _val = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I can post the js code if needed but code is pretty long.

Here is the js and the markup:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.js"></script>  
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">

       <style type="text/css">
       .ui-button { margin-left: -1px; }
       .ui-button-icon-only .ui-button-text { padding: 0.35em; } 
       .ui-autocomplete-input { margin: 0; padding: 0.48em 0 0.47em 0.45em; }
       </style>

       <script type="text/javascript">


           function optionSelected(selectedValue) {
               document.title = selectedValue;
           }

           (function ($) {
               $.widget("ui.combobox", {
                   _create: function () {
                       var self = this,
                                  select = this.element.hide(),
                                  selected = select.children(":selected"),
                                  value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
                       var input = this.input = $("<input>")
                                  .insertAfter(select)
                                  .val(value)
                                  .autocomplete({
                                      delay: 0,
                                      minLength: 0,
                                      source: function (request, response) {
                                          var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                                          response(select.children("option").map(function () {
                                              var text = $(this).text();
                                              if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                                  return {
                                                      label: text.replace(
                                                                           new RegExp(
                                                                                  "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                                                                  $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                                                                  ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                                                           ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                                                      value: text,
                                                      option: this
                                                  };
                                          }));
                                      },
                                      select: function (event, ui) {
                                          ui.item.option.selected = true;
                                          self._trigger("selected", event, {
                                              item: ui.item.option
                                          });
                                          //JK
                                          optionSelected(ui.item.option.value);

                                      },
                                      change: function (event, ui) {
                                          if (!ui.item) {
                                              var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                                                              valid = false;
                                              select.children("option").each(function () {
                                                  if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                                                      this.selected = valid = true;
                                                      return false;
                                                  }
                                              });
                                              if (!valid) {
                                                  // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                                  $(this).val("");
                                                  select.val("");
                                                  input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                                                  return false;
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
                                  })
                                  .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

                       input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                           return $("<li></li>")
                                         .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                                         .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                                          .appendTo(ul);
                       };

                       this.button = $("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>")
                                  .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                                  .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                                  .insertAfter(input)
                                  .button({
                                      icons: {
                                          primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                                      },
                                      text: false
                                  })
                                  .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                                  .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")
                                  .click(function () {
                                      // close if already visible
                                      if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                                          input.autocomplete("close");
                                          return;
                                      }

                                      // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                                      input.autocomplete("search", "");
                                      input.focus();
                                  });
                   },

                   destroy: function () {
                       this.input.remove();
                       this.button.remove();
                       this.element.show();
                       $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
                   }
               });
           })(jQuery);

           $(function () {
               $("#<%= newEmpName.ClientID%>").combobox();
               $("#toggle").click(function () {
                   $("#<%= newEmpName.ClientID%>").toggle();
               });
           });
    </script>




**Markup:**

  <asp:DropDownList ID="newEmpName" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" CssClass="style26" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

Comment: questions. 1. you are using jquery ui autocomplete? 2. you changed the dropdownlist to a textbox to enable autocomplete?

Comment: Are you getting a proper postback still? Also, Can you post the markup for the control and the JS?

Comment: @Geneb, that's the problem, no I am no longer getting the postback.
Naveen, the autocomplete works; that's not the problem and no, I didn't change to textbox but is part of the js.

I have posted the js and the markup.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you have the dropdown list inside of an update panel and, if so, is it set as a trigger?

Comment: @Geneb, I have it inside a  <asp:Panel ID="pnl_main"... but not an update panel.

Comment: I'll be honest.. I am stumped. Is there any way you could provide the actual code for everything so that I can try it on my machine? (Obviously hitting AD won't work, so I'd have to create some test data)

Comment: I don't hit our AD. I set up a scheduled job to update a sql server db with info from AD. I then point this app to SQL Server database. We called the table ActiveDirectory for convenience. The name samAccountName is same as username. But lot files.Is file attachment allowed here?

Comment: I don't think so (but I am not sure, as I am pretty new). Could you zip them up and host them somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

With autocompletion, the selected index is no changing anymore, it is always the first one, with autocompletion the list of possible alternatives is changing, but the index of the selected item is not changing, it is always 0. Try maybe with some trigger based on content.